# jQuery $.post() function difficulty not displaying result?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I am using jQuery's $.post function to retrieve some data from a php file, but the returned data does not seem to be showing? Here is what I have got.

**Javascript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#import").click(function(){
        //This code works when uncommented, used for debugging.
        /*var x = "tester";
        $('input[name=title]').val(x);*/

        $.post("import.php", function(data){
            $('input[name=title]').empty().val(data.name); // John
            $('input[name=subtitle]').empty().val(data.time); //  2pm
            }, "json");
    });
});
```

**PHP import.php Code:**

```
<?php
    $my_array = array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm");
    echo json_encode($my_array); 
?>
```

Is there something silly I've missed out, or have I gone about this incorrectly. I'm fairly new to javascript/jquery.

Comment: What do you get if you put a `console.log(data)` or `alert(data.name)` as the first line of your callback? You don't need to call `.empty()`, because (1) it doesn't make sense to call it on an input element, and (2) `.val()` will overwrite the previous value anyway.

Comment: Thanks for that, .empty() is now removed.

Comment: Solved the issue, I had a button with id="import" but i'd set it's type to submit, instead of button(stupid mistake)! It was resetting my page removing my values from the textboxes as soon as they we're inserted.

Comment: Making stupid mistake is the best form of learning :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use json.parse() and assign it to a variable to use it as an object.

download json2.js from [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

json.parse has [this](http://www.json.org/js.html) documentation.

a request type of JSON does not mean the ajax function returns the "data" value as an object. it is still a string and needs to be parsed with

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(data);
```

then you can use it like

```
alert(myObject.name);
```